# Manipulando chances com JS ao usar Math.random()?

Tags: javascript, random

Ao usar essa função `Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1)` obtenho um número aleatório de 1 até 10. Presumimos que cada número tenha 10% de chance logo temos 50% de chance para Impar ou Par, mas e se eu quisesse manipular essas chances, de forma que a função seja mais propensa a me dar um número Impar, por exemplo 70% de chance de sair um número Impar e 30% de chance de sair um número Par.

1. É possível fazer isso?
2. Qual seria a lógica aplicada e como posso fazer?

Answer (score 3):

O algoritmo abaixo é composto de duas partes:

- `numTipo` é gerado: seu valor será 0 se o retorno de uma geração randômica de 1 a 10 for superior a 8, ou 1 caso negativo; e
- `numFinal` simplesmente contém um valor entre 2 e 100 que *sempre será par*, onde `numTipo` é posteriormente adicionado.

A adição de um valor ímpar a um valor par sempre gerará um valor ímpar. Qualquer outro caso de adição (Par + Par, Ímpar + Ímpar) gera um número par.

Este algoritmo força a geração de valores cuja distribuição média é de 70% ímpares e 30% pares.

```js
function geraNum() {

  var numTipo = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1) > 7 ? 0 : 1;
  var numFinal = Math.floor((Math.random() * 50) + 1) *2 + numTipo;

  return numFinal;
}

function geraSerie() {

    var contaPar = 0;
    var contaImpar = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) { 
        
        if (geraNum() % 2 == 0) {
            contaPar++;
        } else {
            contaImpar++;
        }
    }
    
    console.log("Pares: " + contaPar + ", Ímpares: " + contaImpar);    
}

geraSerie();
geraSerie();
geraSerie();
geraSerie();
geraSerie();
```

Answer (score 0):

O próprio nome já diz `ramdom()`, ou seja, retorna um número randômico. Se você quer alterar as chances do número retornado ser mais par ou ser mais ímpar, você pode criar uma função simples para verificar o retorno do código:

```
let myNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
if (myNumber % 2 == 0) { 
  // par = faça alguma coisa
} else {
  // ímpar = faça alguma coisa
}
```

Porém, como é um retorno randômico, somente com os `if's` você consegue manipular o resultado.

Um outro caminho é você criar sua própria função (Ex: `Math.myRandomFunction()`) e nela você mesmo cria sua lógica, armazenando informações e forçando o retorno ser mais par ou ser mais ímpar.

Answer (score 0):

Seria mais interessante você dizer qual problema exatamente você quer resolver. Mas, segundo seu exemplo, você pode fazer primeiro um sorteio para determinar se o número que você quer é par ou ímpar. Depois, pra casa caso, chame uma função que gera um número somente no padrão que você quer. Por exemplo:

```
if (x > 7) {
    return gerarNumeroPar();
} else {
    return gerarNumeroImpar();
}
```

Essa função pode ser feita selecionando de uma lista previamente gerada ou mesmo sorteando sucessivas vezes até bater com o que você precisa gerar.

Comment: O que está descrito em minha função, é exatamente o problema que quero resolver ... quero gerar um número aleatório entre 1 e 10, porém quero que esse número tenha mais chances de ser Impar.

Comment: Então a minha resposta resolve seu problema. Você entendeu ela?

Comment: "x" é um aleatório ele sendo maior que 7 (70%) eu gero um par, sendo menor seria os 30% sendo um Impar, correto?

Comment: Isso. São dois sorteios. O primeiro é esse X pra determinar se vai ser ímpar ou par. Uma vez determinado isso, chama a função que sorteia em loop até sair o que que bate com o que foi escolhido. Tô no celular, por isso não coloquei mais detalhes. Mais tarde edito pra ficar mais completo, mas a ideia é essa.

Comment: Eu entendi a lógica aplicada, seria essa solução uma "gambiarra" ou não existe uma função mais especifica para manipulação de chances?

Answer (score -3):

Não entendi muito bem, mas se o objetivo é ser mais propício a um resultado, pode-se fazer desta forma:

```
if(valor > 7){
    // 30% de chance de cair aqui 
}else{
    // 70% de chance de cair aqui 
}
```